# Are people reading the questions in the triage queue?

Tags: discussion

How are questions like

*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837766/how-to-create-rfid-application-to-read-and-write-hid-omnikey-5421*

making it through the triage queue? I understand that there is no real way to police this, but this isn't even a question it literally says please code this for me.

Comment: Robo reviewing has always been an issue. Flag such posts accordingly and move on.

Comment: Do you have a reference of people clicking "Looks okay" for this specific question in the triage queue? Questions don't automatically start out in the triage queue. They only get there if they get flagged.

Comment: Was this question in Triage? Can someone provide a link to the review?

Comment: maybe I misspoke, I assumed all first question for any user ended up in triage

Comment: No it got sent to [First Posts](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/15547349) instead, where there is no information on what action was taken on the review task. Only thing I see are close votes that were all cast since this meta post surfaced.

Comment: All first questions end up in the ["First Posts"](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts) queue, but these questions are still visible for everyone during the review.

Comment: that makes sense, thanks for prompt responses. When I see posts like this I always flag them, but it always baffles me when users less than a day old post questions like this and it somehow makes it through without review.

Comment: With a -6 on 1rst question he will have hard time escaping from question ban. But I still think those meta call out are not Worth it. You must flag/comment and let some times at least 12h to 2 days. Meta effect hits really hard.

Comment: @PierreLebon You'll never get question banned as a result of a single question.  Unless they have other deleted poorly received questions, they're not question banned.  They simply need to not ask *more* bad questions going forward.  Even a second question that's not recieved well isn't likely to result in them being question banned until it ends up being *very* poorly received.

Comment: @PierreLebon I was not trying to do a call out, I actually wanted to know how questions like this actually make it to the general user without being reviewed (especially for brand new users). This was just a question that I found today. The intent was not to make it harder for this user to post future question, but rather for me to learn more about the system. When I posted the question I honestly thought these questions were being triaged incorrectly.

Comment: @Servy, I know he won't get question ban for this one. But starting with a -6 it's not a good start. This user did not even read tour. The best we can do now is a generic message leading to tour, ask and mcve.

Comment: @PierreLebon `But starting with a -6 it's not a good start.`  No, it' s not.  And that's not a good question. `This user did not even read tour.` And yet they should have.  They know they should have, and they didn't anyway.  That's *their* fault, not someone else's. `The best we can do now is a generic message leading to tour, ask and mcve.` They've already been shown several such messages already, and they've ignored them thus far, so I wouldn't have high hopes, but it does happen that a few percent of such users do improve, sure.

Comment: @Servy, As you can see my relatively new here. But even for me, they are a pain. But I have hope! If one of them read tour and edit his question. It's worth it even more than 100 upvote for me, or a diner with Jon Sk.

Comment: @PierreLebon By all means, tell the OP information that they already ought to (but clearly don't) know.  I'm not saying you shouldn't.  Just realize both that virtually all of them will ignore you, most that don't won't be willing/able to actually take the time to improve their content.  And just because you want to try to help someone improve their question doesn't change the fact that it's an *awful* question, and absolutely merits closure and downvotes.  Complaining about people downvoting a bad question because there's a 1% chance that the OP might *try* to fix it isn't appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The post was never in Triage in the first place.

Only certain posts get sent to triage; it's those that the system has reason to believe are likely problematic.  This question didn't meet the criteria for it.

Additionally the question is currently 14 minutes old at the time of my answer; it was 5 minutes old at the time of your question.  Even if it *did* get sent to triage; it's unlikely that it would have been able to be closed in that amount of time anyway.